# Not able to convert from NFA to DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have a simple problem of making a DFA which accepts all inputs starting with double letters (aa, bb) or ending with double letters (aa, bb), given $\Sigma =\{a, b\}$ is the alphabet set of the given language.

I tried to solve it in a roundabout way by:

1. Generating a regular expression
2. Making its corresponding NFA
3. Using powerset construction to deduce a DFA
4. Minimizing the number of states in DFA

**Step 1:** *Regular expression* for given problem is (among countless others):

```
((aa|bb)(a|b)*)|((a|b)(a|b)*(aa|bb))
```

**Step 2:** *NFA* for given expression is:

[image: NFA]
<sub>(source: [livefilestore.com](https://qbcweg.sn2.livefilestore.com/y1pi4Jp5zdZjHEzQ61lYnqZtFu8DQ9B9qS0TyTX2HXh1ZJDDYAmokxBQf4orLezYEon6ct94vJJ18Z8AhfyBHHaBrVp18YEA8aa/automata%20question.jpg))</sub>

In Tabular form, NFA is:

```
State    Input:a     Input:b
->1        2,5         3,5
  2        4           -
  3        -           4
 (4)       4           4
  5        5,7         5,6
  6        -           8
  7        8           -
 (8)       -           -
```

**Step 3:** Convert into a DFA using powerset construction:

```
Symbol, State       +   Symbol, State (Input:a) +   Symbol, State (Input:b)
   ->A, {1}         |        B, {2,5}           |        C, {3,5}
     B, {2,5}       |        D, {4,5,7}         |        E, {5,6}
     C, {3,5}       |        F, {5,7}           |        G, {4,5,6}
   (D), {4,5,7}     |        H, {4,5,7,8}       |        G, {4,5,6}
     E, {5,6}       |        F, {5,7}           |        I, {5,6,8}
     F, {5,7}       |        J, {5,7,8}         |        E, {5,6}
   (G), {4,5,6}     |        D, {4,5,7}         |        K, {4,5,6,8}
   (H), {4,5,7,8}   |        H, {4,5,7,8}       |        G, {4,5,6}
   (I), {5,6,8}     |        F, {5,7}           |        I, {5,6,8}
   (J), {5,7,8}     |        J, {5,7,8}         |        E, {5,6}
   (K), {4,5,6,8}   +        D, {4,5,7}         +        K, {4,5,6,8}
```

**Step 4:** Minimize the DFA:

I have changed K->G, J->F, I->E first. In the next iteration, H->D and E->F. Thus, the final table is:

```
  State    +   Input:a     +   Input:b
   ->A     |      B        |      C
     B     |      D        |      E
     C     |      E        |      D
    (D)    |      D        |      D
    (E)    |      E        |      E
```

And diagramatically it looks like:

[image: Final DFA]
<sub>(source: [livefilestore.com](https://yhtvma.sn2.livefilestore.com/y1pW43x0q2NHkqp6KEDLVS95HinOgTt-VM3obaUiIJvEe4yBNecx0abQh4P7HOC5Emj6sMnfqsDim0fk3kS0ovA-l3Rf7_GoCxB/automata%20question%20final%20dfa.jpg))</sub>

...which is not the required DFA! I have triple checked my result. So, where did I go wrong?

Note:

- -> = initial state
- () = final state

Comment: This is a great example for a basic question that has been posed well, because you include your whole train of thought.

Comment: Feels great to be appreciated, thanks! ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are fine up to step 3 (the DFA) but your minimization is incorrect.

It's clear that the minimized DFA is not right, because both the inputs `ba` and `ab` (which are not in the original language, nor are they accepted by the DFA in step 3) lead to final state `E`.

Looking at your minimization steps, it seems that you have unified final and non-final states; for example J (final) -> F (not final) and I (final) -> E (not final). Merging a final state with a non-final state changes the language accepted by the automaton, leading to the acceptance of incorrect strings as noted above.

Comment: Oh. So, that is what is creating problem here. Now that I remember, the last time I used this method, there weren't any particular accepting states at all in the table!